# Can't sync MS Project with Project Task List

Tags: list, synchronisation, ms-project

As the title says I'm not able to sync my MS Project plan with a SharePoint Task List.
I created the list and synced it, then I made some changes and want to sync again, which throws the following error:

> Ungültiger Sammelvorgangsname
>
> Das Projekt kann nicht mit der SharePoint-Vorgangsliste synchronisiert
>   werden, da mindestens zwei Sammelvorgänge den gleichen Namen
>   aufweisen.
>
> Ändern Sie den Namen von xxx, und wiederholen Sie die
>   Synchronisierung.

Which means in english something like

> Invalid group task
>
> The Project can't be synchronised with the SharePoint-Tasklist,
>   because at least 2 group tasks have the same name.
>
> Please change the name of xxx and repeat the synchronisation.

I had this issue before and had to delete the list and sync again (which was no problem with the fresh list, so the project plan must be ok).
I created a new project from the existing list just to test it and there really were tasks with the same name like my group tasks as regular tasks, but I never added them and they are not part of my original project plan.

Does anybody know about this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: my problem is unwanted sync works fine : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/203496/5170